# Visual Studio SDK: Where is the AssemblyFolderEx registry key for Windows Phone Game projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am trying to tell the setup program to add PostSharp to the "Add Reference" dialog box of Visual Studio for Windows Phone 7 projects.

I figured out that the registry key for Windows Phone Applications is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight for Phone\v4.0\AssemblyFoldersEx.

What's the corresponding key for Windows Phone Games?

Answer (score 0):

If the assembly is in the GAC you can use "**Add GAC Reference**" menu item it's simple and faster than "Add Reference" dialog. For additional details please review the following article: [Muse VSReferences](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879?wa=wsignin1.0)

The **Add GAC Reference** dialog box displays all  GAC assemblies.

s

Comment: I don't want to add the assembly in local GAC (it does not even make sense since I am targetting Windows Phone), and I am looking for a solution that works without additional extension.